# Why is npx create-react-app dojo-blog not working when I type it in my command prompt

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxD9N.png)

When I run `npx create-react-app dojo-blog`, it starts installing. After some time it throws up that error in the image attached.

Answer (score 0):

Check if node is properly installed by running `node -v`. If so, then maybe there is some problem in your network. Please check your network connection and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a problem with network connection. You can try to increase timeout. Don't know the reason of your network issues, but it may help:

```bash
npx create-react-app dojo-blog -timeout=60000
```